# Python: PBS submission, what happens if I change script?

Tags: python, pbs, qsub

I have a script `job.bin` for executing a code in python (`pythoncode.py`) on a cluster, submitting jobs via `qsub`. In `job.bin`:

```
cd /path/to/my/python/code
python pythoncode.py
```

What happens if:

a) while `pythoncode.py` is running, I change its content

b) while `pythoncode.py` is held on queue, I change its content

`pythoncode.py` contains some parameters that I can vary. In situations a) and b), will a change of any of these parameters affect the already begun or queuing run?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. When you change `job.bin` after you submitted your job **nothing happens** because the submission file is copied to a temporary storage by `qsub`.
2. When you change `pythoncode.py` while job is held in the queue the **new version of the file will be run** as the job script is read after the job state is changed to *running* by the scheduler.
3. When you change `pythoncode.py` while the job is running **nothing happens** as the python interpreter has already started and read the script into its own memory.

Pro tip. Admin can change the `job.bin` file held in the temporary storage while the job is held in the queue so that the new version of `job.bin` will run.